# Bootstrap navbar centers items only on mobile

Tags: html, navbar, bootstrap-5

I have a navbar made using bootstrap. I have the desired behavior on large screens, with the user dropdown and currency on the end of the navbar, and the logo on the left.
[Large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrjfl.png)

However on small screens, the hamburger menu goes on the right of the dropdown, which I want, however it causes the dropdown to be centered rather than on the right. I have tried searching around for solutions, which have helped me get to this point, but I am stuck with this undesired behavior.
[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Ybm.png)

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md cus-bg-elevated d-flex sticky-top cus-box-shadow">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-start order-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://url.net">
    <img src="https://www.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="Bootstrap" width="30" height="24">
    </a>
    <p>a</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-end order-md-4 order-1">
<li class="nav-item d-flex dropdown">
    <p class="text-warning" style="margin:5px 5px 0 0;font-size:18px;">$</p>
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa-regular fa-user" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" style="padding-top:0;font-size:16px;">
            <p class="text-light bg-secondary" style="margin:0px;padding:2px 2px 2px 6px;border-radius:4.7px 4.7px 0 0;">user</p>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" style="margin-top:0;"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://url.net/users?id="/><i class="fa-light fa-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://url.net/settings/"><i class="fa-light fa-gear"></i> Settings</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-danger" href="http://fans.great-site.net/logout"><i class="fa-light fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i> Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </div>

    <button class="navbar-toggler order-3" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon order-3"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Welcome, please add an editable version and source code, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The markup you show is invalid. You have a `<li>` but no parent `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your editable code, I would suspect what is occurring is at the mobile media query in Bootstrap it is defaulting to `justify-content: center;` as bootstrap uses flex-box. Inspect your CSS at the mobile break point when it's being centered and see if your `.navbar` element has `justify-content: center;` on it. If so, change that to the default `justify-content: flex-start;` or `justify-content: space-between;`

Comment: His markup is now there but, until then, do not answer questions without code as they are considered off topic. [answer]